# How to suppress an informational raiserror message

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I have a setup script that calls `sp_configure` a few times to set up some system variables, it works fine but I have a few of the following statement

> Configuration option '%ls' changed from %ld to %ld. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

with the variables filled in accordingly. Internally I can see sp_configure is calling

```
raiserror(15457,-1,-1, @configname, @prevvalue, @configvalue) with log
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent those informational messages (which are useless to the script, I call `RECONFIGURE` from inside the script) from displaying in the messages window in MSSMS when a user runs the script?

Comment: Im running into this as well. In part of one of my scripts I want it to enable XP_CMDSHELL, and then when the execution is complete I want it to disable it. In my case, the confirmation message interferes with my process. I do not want the message stating: "Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install." There must be some tricky way to eliminate this from the output. Thoughts??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Informational messages cannot be suppressed.